# Implementing Odoo SSO with Microsoft ADFS

Tags: odoo, single-sign-on, adfs

We have to integrate Microsoft ADFS authentication into our Odoo applications and broaden the scope of current SSO.

I seriously have no idea of how this work as I have no experience with ADFS. Can anyone with experience of this explain it with a scenario of how it works so that I can understand it and think of a solution to it.

Comment: Any ideas please :(  ?

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/SerpentcsConsulting/microsoft-azure-odoo-sso-integration

Comment: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/odoo_microsoft_account/

Answer (score 0):

Odoo supports SAML:
https://github.com/xcgd/auth_saml

So I figured you can set the ADFS to communicate with SAML:
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Configuring_ADFS_3.0_to_Communicate_with_SAML_2.0#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Hi,

Have you used the above module with any IDP? I got some issues with certificate validation despite even trying with a purhcased certificate for the IDP. The lasso part is causing some issue